# Is there a way to add a variable to Regex and use them in JavaScript or TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, regex, typescript

I am trying to use something similar to

```
/^(.*?)\.txt/
```

But instead of using .txt I want to replace it with a variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use the RegExp constructor.

```js
var extension = ".txt";
var reg = new RegExp("^(.*?)\\" + extension);

console.log(reg);
console.log(reg.test("test.txt"));
console.log(reg.test("test.pdf"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```js
function extMatch(ext){
    return new RegExp('^(.*?)\\.'+ext+'$');
}
/*  Even shorter, but messing with base prototypes is frowned upon.
    Use at your leisure. */
String.prototype.extMatch=function(ext){
    let match=this.match(extMatch(ext));
    return match && match[1];
}
let str='foobar.css';
let ext='css';
console.log(str.match(extMatch(ext))[1]);
console.log(str.extMatch(ext));

console.log(str.extMatch('zip'));       // null if no match
```